# What does it mean when a variable appears red in the visual studio C++ debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, variables

what does it mean when a variable appears red in the visual studio C++ debugger? I assume not good.

Thanks.

Comment: Try moving mouse over the variable, VS will probably tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Its value changed during the last 'step'. Don't worry, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to check what the *last step* is? I can't seem to debug to it.

Comment: You mean that it's just a way to show you which is the last of the watch variables which has changed, which might be useful if you have lots of variables being watched.